# Issue with ternary operator JS

Tags: javascript

I have a questions. So I am making a timer and it works fine but for one thing. So when minutes < 10 it should add 0 before. However, when condition is true it adds a lot of 0)). Also, when the timer reaches to 00:00 it should stop but the seconds remain on 00:01.

```js
class Timer{
    constructor(minute,second){
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second
    }
    start(){
        let s = this.second;
        let m = this.minute
        let h1 = document.createElement("h1")
        timer.addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
            let time = setInterval(()=>{
                s = s >= 10?s : "0" + s;
               // m = m >= 10?m : "0" + m;//
                h1.innerHTML = m + ":" + s
                console.log(this)
                s--
                if(m == 0 && s == 0){
                    clearInterval(time)
                }
                if(s == 0){
                    m--
                    s=59
                }
                console.log(s)
            },1)
            
        })
        document.body.append(h1)
        
    }
}
let time = new Timer(2,20)
time.start()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="timer">Timer</button>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Can you please check the attached code?Thank you!

Comment: Just a general remark,
You have a mixed logic here. I'd recommend splitting this whole functionality into 2 parts:
1) pure function which would generate a string based on another string (time)
2) updating the DOM with the result of the first function

This way you'd be able to test the first part with unit tests easily.
This is where your problem lies

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
s = s >= 10?s : "0" + s;
```

you're (potentially) turning `s` into a string, so,  for example, if `s` had the value of the *number* `6` now it becomes the *string* `"06"`.

A few lines below you're trying to preform: `s--` which means you're trying to subtract 1 from a string.

Same comment applies to `m` for the line which is currently commented out.

Trying to separate the numeric values you're working with from the display variables you're using in the HTML - will help.

Another recommendation which is unrelated: don't use one-letter variable names (with the exception of an index in a for-loop): rename `s` to `seconds` (or if you really want to save some ket-strokes to `secs`) and `m` to `minutes`. By doing that you're making your code easier to read, and as we all know: we read code way more than we write it, so optimize for reading is the right thing to do!

There may be additional issues, but you can start with this one and take it from there.